# What causes slow SSH command execution?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, window

I work on a MacBook Pro and connect remotely to a PC (Windows 10 with OpenSSH server) and run tester or builds.

At least that's the theory. I have no problem accessing the PC from the Mac. However, when I run a "make" command, for example, it takes an insanely longer time than if I ran it directly on the machine. The communication over SSH itself is fast, that's not the problem, the command itself is just executed slowly on the computer.

Both computers are on the same local network. If I execute the same command directly on the computer, then such a make needs maybe two to three minutes, if I execute the same command over SSH, it needs 30 minutes and more.

When I access another computer (Linux/Mac) from the Windows PC via SSH client, I have not yet noticed such a behavior.

What can cause such a behavior? Is this normal or have I simply not noticed it yet?
I'm not very knowledgeable about SSH, so I'd appreciate some help!

Thanks in advance!